# svg shape animation not working properly on fixed position by using green socks

Tags: html, css, gsap

I am working on SVG animations, trying to make an SVG path animation but not getting a flexible animation. I have tried the [link provided](https://codepen.io/arshiyakhanam_786/pen/mNyxJB), please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance...

```css
.ocean { 
  height: 5%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background: #015871;
}

.wave {
  // background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/85486/wave.svg) repeat-x; 
  position: absolute;
  top: -198px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
  // transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: -175px;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) -.125s infinite, swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="780" viewBox="0 0 1920 780"><g><g opacity=".75"><path fill="#ffefdd" d="M518.416 278.813c100.975 408.098 513.434 328.466 588.907 253.974 75.473-74.493 153.228-259.973 324.949-282.534 154.635-20.315 317.211-182.93 487.728-78.482v453.068c-264.98 2.452-323.019-161.187-601.137 25.146-320.667 214.84-339.51 105.56-508.484 75.563S535.477 828.256 326.51 643.775C188.975 522.356 98.538 508.728 0 535.407V0h260.293c113.729 39.308 218.825 119.99 258.123 278.813z" class="wave"/></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: Hey Arshiya, I see that this is tagged [tag:greensock] but I don't see GS in the JS (or any JS at all). Are you wondering how to use GSAP's [MorphSVG](https://greensock.com/morphSVG)? Or something else?

Comment: I want to animate the SVG path by using GSAP's.

Comment: If I were you I would [read this page about animating SVGs in GSAP](https://greensock.com/svg-tips).

Comment: @Zach Saucier Thanks for providing this link. I tried a lot to animate the SVG path by using GSAP but still, it's not animating. please help me to sort out this.